Fetch NFT holders
I want to fetch the NFT holders. I want to pass the address of an NFT and get back all the previous holders of that NFT. I already obtained the collection's holders, but now I need the NFT holders.

You can get use getTokenLargestAccounts to get the current holder of an NFT, but you can't get historical holders without looking through historical transactions for transfers
